# Connecting in Narita from Domestic ANA 1162 to International Delta 68; Baggage?

Tags: transit, japan, nrt, delta-air-lines, ana

I will fly on Sept 30 from Osaka to Narita on ANA 1162, arriving at 13:35. I am then traveling from Narita to PDX on Delta 68 at 4:10 PM.

How/where do I claim my bags and recheck them for the Delta flight?

---

Different bookings. Already have a booking on Delta 68 which leaves Terminal 1N, Gate 18, @ 4PM to Portland, Oregon. I'm travelling on ANA Flt 1162 from Osaka arriving at Narita @ 13:35. I will have checked bags at Osaka and don't know where to claim the bags @ Narita and where to recheck them for the Delta flight. I believe the ANA arrives @ Terminal 1 in the Domestic area somewhere, but I don't know where. I will also ask the check-in staff at Osaka to check my bags through.

Comment: Are you asking if you have enough time to make the connection? Are the tickets on the same reservation? Or are you asking where baggage claim is for your terminal? In that case, which terminal?

Comment: Your baggage will normally be checked through zll the way. If the flights are not on the same ticket, inform the check-in staff at Osaka that you have a connection.

Comment: Same booking number? or different bookings?

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment, it will most likely be possible to have your baggage checked through all the way, even on different bookings, if you inform the check-in staff in Osaka that you have a connection (they will probably ask you about it, as well).

Assuming it's not possible, however, with more than three hours you have more than enough time to treat your flights as completely separate: collect your luggage at the main collection point in the arrivals area as if you did not have a connection, and proceed to the Delta check-in counter in the departures area as if you had arrived to the airport by train or whatever. Everything will be clearly indicated.

If your incoming flight is delayed, inform airline staff as soon as possible and they will do what they can.